# Configure Tortoisegit

Tags: git, tortoisegit

As a consultant I might have to deal with different Git repositories, BeanStalk, BitBucket, etc.  I was wondering how do I configure Tortoisegit to work with a setup like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No matter how is hosted the git repository, all you need is its URL (`git://github.com/user/project.git` or `https://bitbucket.org/user/project.git`, for example). This is what you give to TortoiseGit on cloning configuration.

For authentication, see for example [GitHub docs for SSH setup with TortoiseGit](https://github.com/multitheftauto/multitheftauto/wiki/How-to-use-tortoisegit-%28historical-page%29), but you shoud use HTTPS authentication which is simpler.

Comment: How do I handle the authentication portion?

Comment: I just wanted to say that the link you have provided for GitHub docs has 4 bullet points, with neither leading to a detailed description on setting up the authentication portion with tortoisegit.

Comment: @Killrawr the page has been vandalized since; hold on for a permalink

Comment: @Killrawr sorry about your question, was busy at understanding how to restore github pages. The link is correct now.

Comment: If all Bitbucket needs is a url, how do you prevent someone else from accessing that Bitbucket repository? (or is there some authentication between the two that I'm missing)?

Comment: Link to github.com is 404